# Breakpoint debugger for sails.js

Tags: node.js, debugging, sails.js

I have been trying and failing to get basic breakpoints working in a fresh sails js app.

I create a new sails project called test and added a couple lines of code so I could hit a route and try to initiate a breakpoint in my terminal:

```
//  app/controllers/TestController.js

module.exports = {
  test: function (req, res) {
    console.log('test');
    debugger;
    return res.json({
      text: 'hello',
    });
  }
}
```

in my routes file:

```
//  /config/routes.js
'get /test': 'TestController.test',
```

then I go to my terminal and use nodemon to launch the sails server with:

```
$ nodemon debug -w . app.js
```

My one caveat is that this solution should work with something like nodemon, forever, or supervisor that will allow for livereload on the nodeserver